# c# linq GroupBy on the values of a List within a List

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I have a List of Objects and within the Object there is a List of strings. What I want to do is find out how many of each string value there are.

So to create a simple example with the languages spoken by people in a team.

```
public class PeopleLanguages
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Languages;
}
```

Create the test data...

```
List<PeopleLanguages> peopleLanguages = new List<PeopleLanguages>();

peopleLanguages.Add(new PeopleLanguages { Name = "Rod", Languages = new List<string> { "English", "French", "German" } });
peopleLanguages.Add(new PeopleLanguages { Name = "Jane", Languages = new List<string> { "English", "Spanish", "Greek" } });
peopleLanguages.Add(new PeopleLanguages { Name = "Fredie", Languages = new List<string> { "French", "Arabic", "Italian" } });
peopleLanguages.Add(new PeopleLanguages { Name = "Viktor", Languages = new List<string> { "English", "Krakozhian" } });
```

To visualise the data:

```
 * Rod => English | French | German
 * Jane => English | Spanish | Greek
 * Fredie => French | Arabic | Italian
 * Viktor => English | Krakozhian
```

I can get the result I want by finding the distinct string values using `SelectMany().Distinct()` then matching within a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (string language in peopleLanguages.SelectMany(p => p.Languages).Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{language} = {peopleLanguages.Where(p => p.Languages.Contains(language)).Count()}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
English = 3
French = 2
German = 1
Spanish = 1
Greek = 1
Arabic = 1
Italian = 1
Krakozhian = 1
```

But there has to be a better way to do this using `GroupBy()`.

I'm just stuck about how to get the individual distinct values out of the List of languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwWFKc)

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to get a list of list langues, then `GroupBy` as you wish like below

```
var result = peopleLanguages
    .SelectMany(p => p.Languages)
    .GroupBy(p => p);
    
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Count()}");
}
```

**Output**

```
English : 3
French : 2
German : 1
Spanish : 1
Greek : 1
Arabic : 1
Italian : 1
Krakozhian : 1
```

Comment: Perfect solution... knew I had to be missing something simple because it's hardly an unusual objective :)

Comment: Yes, It's my pleasure.